# I want to create a Max date column grouped by Order ID

Tags: r

I want to create a highest shipping date column based for each order id.

I have used the following code. However not getting the desired result.

```
d5<-d4%>% group_by('Order ID') %>% mutate(Max_Date=max('Ship Date'))
```

I have pasted the table below

```
      Order ID  Ship Date   Max_Ship Date   Product ID  Category    Sales
CA-2012-124891  7/31/2019   7/31/2019   OFF-BI-10003527 Technology  2309.65
CA-2012-124891  7/15/2019   7/31/2019   FUR-TA-10000198 Technology  3709.395
CA-2012-124891  7/17/2019   7/31/2019   OFF-SU-10002881 Technology  5175.171
IN-2013-77878   2/15/2019   2/15/2019   FUR-TA-10001889 Furniture   2892.51
IN-2013-77878   2/7/2019    2/15/2019   TEC-CIS-10001717    Furniture   2832.96
IN-2013-71249   12/18/2018  2/15/2019   FUR-CH-10002033 Technology  2862.675
IN-2013-71249   10/5/2018   2/15/2019   OFF-AP-10003500 Technology  1822.08
IN-2013-71249   1/7/2019    2/15/2019   OFF-AP-10000423 Technology  5244.84
IN-2013-71249   10/18/2018  2/15/2019   TEC-AC-10004145 Technology  5083.96
IN-2013-71249   10/18/2018  2/15/2019   OFF-AP-10004512 Technology  4297.644
ES-2013-1579342 1/30/2019   1/30/2019   TEC-CO-10000865 Technology  4164.05
```

Comment: You can't do `'Order ID'` in `dplyr` this will create a new column, use the column name without `''`. Given you have space in column names so you need `\`\``, e.g. `d4%>% group_by(\`Order ID\`) %>% mutate(Max_Date=max(\`Ship Date\`))`

Comment: Hi @A.Suliman, thanks for the update. However I have changed the column name as Order.ID. then also the code is not working

Comment: Try `d4%>% dplyr::group_by(Order.ID) %>% mutate(Max_Date=max(\`Ship Date\`))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the data to standard Date format and then do `group_by` and `max`

```
library(dplyr)

d4 %>%
   mutate(ShipDate = as.Date(ShipDate, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
   #Or mutate(ShipDate = lubridate::mdy(ShipDate)) %>%
   group_by(OrdeID) %>%
   mutate(max_date = max(ShipDate))
```

Or in base R, use `ave`

```
df$Max_Ship_date <- with(df, ave(as.Date(ShipDate, "%m/%d/%Y"), OrdeID, FUN = max))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'OrdeID', convert the 'ShipDate' to `Date` with `mdy` from `lubridate` and get the `max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
 df %>% 
   group_by(OrdeID) %>%
   mutate(max_date = max(mdy(ShipDate)))
```

Or use `anytime`, which can directly pick up any date format

```
library(anytime)
df %>%
    group_by(OrdeID) %>%
    mutate(max_date = max(anydate(ShipDate)))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, max_date := max(mdy(ShipDate)), .(OrdeID)]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$max_date <- do.call(c, lapply(with(df, split(as.Date(ShipDate,
         "%m/%d/%Y"), OrdeID)), max))
```

Comment: Just to note, `mdy` is not a base R function.

Comment: @Parfait It is in another post.  I was thinking about that